# Stacking Landsat band in Sentinel collection using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel

I have worked on the following code to obtain a fusion of both sensors but when I generate it I get Landsat as an additional property, what can I do?

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE', "19HCD"))
    .filterBounds(subsubcuencas_ms);
//print(s2);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filterBounds(subsubcuencas_ms);
//print(l8);

var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('landsat').apply({
  primary: s2,
  secondary: l8,
  condition: ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.maxDifference({
      difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // One day in milliseconds
      leftField: 'system:time_start',
      rightField: 'system:time_start',
    }),
    ee.Filter.intersects({
      leftField: '.geo',
      rightField: '.geo',
    })
  )
});

print(joined, 'joined')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your last comment I understood that the desired output is an image collection of Sentinel-2 images where the Landsat 8 bands are added as bands. After doing the join, the landsat images that matched the indicated condition are saved as a property of each Sentinel-2 image. The only thing you have to do is extract that property, convert it to an image collection and maybe mosaic the images (if you have more than one landsat 8 image that matched the condition). Finally you just need to add this image's bands to the original Sentinel-2 one.

```
// Map over each of the Sentinel-2 image in joined
var resul = joined.map(function(image){
  // Get property 'landsat' and transform it to an image collection
  // (from a list of images)
  var l8 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(image.get('landsat'));
  // Maybe use mosaic if you have more than one match, if not, you can 
  // use first() instead.
  l8 = l8.mosaic();
  // Add the l8 bands to the sentinel-2 ones
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(l8);
});

// Convert the resul to an image collection (from a list of images)
resul = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(resul);
```

Comment: yes, I have tried doing this process but it is not what I need as it only joins the collections and does not add sentinel as a band to the landsat image, thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer based on this last comment that clears out which is the desired output.