# Joining Sentinel-1 Collection to Landsat C2 T2

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, attribute-joins

I am interested in creating a time series of Landsat from 2000 to 2022. I want to join Sentinel-1 as an additional band to each Landsat Image in the image collection before I aggregate my date to create annual composites where data is available and at the same incidence of time where data is available (2015-Present for Sentinel).
I attempted to follow the recommendations from [this thread on stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408566/stacking-landsat-band-in-sentinel-collection-using-google-earth-engine-javascrip). I essentially followed the same approach but I switched the order of the collections. Here is my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d2a8c1e1e662c653c557e783aa8e5c91). I designed my code to be replicable, my actual script is at a longer time scale with additional processing.

Snippet that produces error:

```
    var s1 = joined.map(function(image){
    var s1 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.Image(image).get('SENTINEL1'));
s1 = s1.mosaic()
return ee.Image(image).addBands(s1);
});
```

Error:

```
Image(Error)
argument 'images':Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual Type: ImageCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is already an image collection. Just drop this line:

```
result = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work in terms of removing previous error. Although when I printed my result it remains as a feature collection object. I will edit my question to reflect the new issue along with my test to fix that.